# Latest keycloak server v21.0.0 admin api - create a realm failed

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak-rest-api

Keycloak server v21.0.0 - Windows 10 - Admin API - create realm failed
How i fix the issue? what will be the issue? please help/support

start the server in dev mode

```
set KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
set KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
.\kc.bat start-dev --http-port 4444
```

admin-cli - to get the access token

```
curl -L -X POST "http://localhost:4444/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" ^
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ^
--data-urlencode "client_id=admin-cli" ^
--data-urlencode "grant_type=password" ^
--data-urlencode "username=admin" ^
--data-urlencode "password=admin"
```

I got the access token and using that token here

```
set TOKEN="eyJh..."
```

**To create a realm**

```
curl --silent --show-error -L -X POST "http://localhost:4444/admin/realms" ^
-d "{\"realm\" : \"test-realm\"}" ^
-H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
-H "Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%"
```

**Error Response**
{"error":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the master access token's `Lifespan` is one minute as default.

It is easy expired during you assign the Token environment variable and call to create realm.

[image]

So you needs to more time when you debugging or manual REST API calling by curl.

[image]

And this curl command makes reduce to copy/paste the token from first get token to assign environment variable.

I am using [git bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) and
[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) for windows.

#### #1 launching Keycloak 21.0.0 by docker

```
docker run -p 4444:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.0 start-dev
```

#### #2 Get Master Access Token and assign into MASTER_TOKEN variable.

```
MASTER_TOKEN=$(curl --silent --location --request POST "http://localhost:4444/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' | jq -r '.access_token')
echo $MASTER_TOKEN
```

[image]

#### #3 Create realm

```
curl --silent --show-error -L -X POST "http://localhost:4444/admin/realms" \
-d "{\"realm\" : \"test-realm\"}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ""$MASTER_TOKEN"
```

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bench Vue!!, highly appreciated, issue resolved

Comment: @NarayanaBasetty, No problem I am happy to hear you got it. Can you vote to me, now I just an accept my answer. It will give me 10 points more. Thanks!

Comment: Where to vote Sir?